# Given $T=(X_{(1)},\sum[X_i-X_{(1)}])$ is minimum sufficient statistics for exp(a,b).

Tags: statistical-inference, sufficient-statistics

Given $T=(X_{(1)},\sum[X_i-X_{(1)}])$ is minimum sufficient statistics for exp(a,b). Show that $X_{(1)}$ and $\sum[X_i-X_{(1)}]$ are independently distributed as $Exp(a,b/n)$ and $\frac{1}{2}b\chi_{(n-2)}^2$, respectively.

I have supposed a new variable $Y_1=X_{(1)}$, $Y_i=X_{(i)}-X_{(i-1)}$, i=2,3,... and I have found the pdf of $Y_i$, and then I would like to show each $Y_i$ independently first, but I failed...

Do you have any other ideas for this question? I am struggling now.

--------------------UPDATES--------------------------

I am know confused that why $\sum[X_i-X_{(1)}]$ could follows chi-squared distribution, since I found Y_i is exponential and $X_i-X_{(1)}$ is just gamma, how could I figure out its chi-squared?

Comment: What is exp(a,b)? Please define it. Also my guess is that this is what most people call Gamma(a,b)

Comment: Hi, the exp(a,b) is exponential distribution with pdf $\frac{1}{b} e^{(x-a)/b}$,where $a<x<inf$.

Comment: Oh so it’s the standard exp(b) distribution shifted by a. Okay, I think you’re going down a strange track. Why don’t you define $W_1=X_{(1)}$ and $W_i=X_i-X_{(1)}$ for $i>1$ instead? These seem more obviously independent, and are more related to the claim in your question.

Comment: Why do you say W1 and Wi are independent?

Comment: about your update, try https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118676/relationship-between-gamma-and-chi-squared-distribution